# validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div> problem

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I am using `material-ui` in my `react.js` project. When I try to test my `Row` component, I get that `console.error`:

```
  Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
```

Here is my `Row` component:

```
const Row: React.FC<RowProps> = ({ course }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const classes = useRowStyles();

  const isDesktopOrLaptop = useMediaQuery({
    query: '(min-device-width: 992px)',
  });

  const boxMargin = isDesktopOrLaptop ? 8 : 1;

  return (
    <>
      <TableRow className={classes.root}>
        <TableCell>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="expand row"
            size="small"
            onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
            {open ? (
              <KeyboardArrowUpIcon fontSize="large" />
            ) : (
              <KeyboardArrowDownIcon fontSize="large" />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          <Typography variant="h5" component="h5">
            {course.course}
          </Typography>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">
          <Typography variant="h5" component="h5">
            {course.openedLessonsCount}
          </Typography>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
          <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <Box marginX={boxMargin} marginY={1}>
              <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom component="h5">
                Projects
              </Typography>
              <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>
                      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="h6">
                        Name
                      </Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">
                      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="h6">
                        Completed Lessons
                      </Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {course.projects &&
                    course.projects.map((project: IProject) => (
                      <TableRow key={project.project}>
                        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                          <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                            {project.project}
                          </Typography>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">
                          <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                            {project.completedLessonsCount}
                          </Typography>
                        </TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </Box>
          </Collapse>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </>
  );
};
```

And here is generated snapshot for it:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <tr
      class="MuiTableRow-root makeStyles-root-1"
    >
      <td
        class="MuiTableCell-root"
      >
        <button
          aria-label="expand row"
          class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-sizeSmall"
          tabindex="0"
          type="button"
        >
          <span
            class="MuiIconButton-label"
          >
            <svg
              aria-hidden="true"
              class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeLarge"
              focusable="false"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <path
                d="M7.41 8.59L12 13.17l4.59-4.58L18 10l-6 6-6-6 1.41-1.41z"
              />
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span
            class="MuiTouchRipple-root"
          />
        </button>
      </td>
      <th
        class="MuiTableCell-root"
        role="cell"
        scope="row"
      >
        <h5
          class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h5"
        >
          Course1
        </h5>
      </th>
      <td
        class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-alignRight"
      >
        <h5
          class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h5"
        >
          3
        </h5>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr
      class="MuiTableRow-root"
    >
      <td
        class="MuiTableCell-root"
        colspan="6"
        style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px;"
      />
    </tr>
  </div>
</body>
```

So it looks like the problem is the `<div>` element inside the `<body>`, but I don't know how to fix that error. I use `React.Fragment` (`<>`) to grab these two of `TableRow`, so that `<div>` shouldn't exist in my opinion...

That `Row` component I took from `material-ui` docs for collapsible table:
https://material-ui.com/components/tables/

And there is codesandbox code for it (also from docs):
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-fnisr?file=/demo.js

@@ UPDATE

I had to wrap Row component with `<table>` and `<tbody>`. I've created a wrapper for that. This is how the test code looks like now:

```
const Wrapper: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>{children}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

test('Basic render', () => {
  const component = render(
    <Wrapper>
      <Row course={props} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
  expect(component.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the demo the rows are wrapped in a table head or table body element, you need to add valid context in your component also.

Contexts in which a `tr` element [can be used](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tr-element):

> As a child of a thead element.
> As a child of a tbody element.
> As a child of a tfoot element.
> As a child of a table element, after any caption, colgroup, and thead elements, but only if there are no tbody elements that are children of the table element.

The parent `div` is not from your custom `Row` component, but from where you render `<Row />`.

Comment: I understand that. But I have all of that inside my another component which contains the `Row`. The snapshot of that another component looks like that:
`<table><tbody><Row></Row></tbody></table>`>
So now when I want to test only Row there is a problem, cos tests doesn't know about the rest of wrapping table elements...

Comment: I have no idea how you test it. If your DOM structure is otherwise valid you can possibly ignore the error or mount the component in a valid context in your test runner.

Comment: Ok, I forgot that I can add some html tags inside `render()` method in tests. I've created a wrapper which add the `<table>` and `<tbody>`. I added to the update section of my question.

Answer (score 1):

The `tr` element must have parent `table` element. So, wrapping your component with table will solve the issue.

The `tr` cannot be descendent of div element.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your component with tbody

For example,

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```